# Задача о покрытии набора точек отрезками равной длины

Tags: c++, алгоритм, функции, оптимизация

Существует классическая задача о покрытии точек отрезками - на числовой оси находятся n целочисленных точек и задача просит найти минимальное количество отрезков указанной длины способных покрыть все точки. Точка считается покрытой если находится на границе отрезка. Например, нам даны пять точек с координатами {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} и отрезки единичной длины - для такого набора ответ на задачу будет 3, тк все точки можно покрыть 3 отрезками [1,2], [3,4], [4,5], двумя отрезками этого не выйдет. Такая задача легко решается жадным алгоритмом.

```
int Cover(std::vector<int>& data, int l) {
//сортируем вектор координат точек
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    

    int interval_count = 1; // количество отрезков
    int r_point = data[0] + l; //правая граница последнего установленного отрезка
    for(int& elem : data){
        if(elem > r_point){
            interval_count += 1;
            r_point = elem + l;
        }
    }
    
    return interval_count;
}
```

Так вот меня интересует обратная задача - найти минимальную длину отрезков, когда по условию дан набор точек и количество отрезков. На самом деле ничего лучше перебора разных длин я не придумал :(
Своё решение я построил на основе бинарного поиска по длинам в диапазоне (0, data.back() - data.front()). Каждая длина в поиске ставится в проверку - покроют ли k отрезков (по условию) длиной l набор точек data (переделанное решение классической задачи.

```
bool CanCover(const std::vector<int>& data, int l, int k){
    
    --k;
    int r_point = data[0] + l;
    
    for(const int& elem : data){
        if(elem > r_point){
            --k;
            r_point = elem + l;
            if (k < 0) return false;
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Вот сам бинарный поиск

```
int Binary(std::vector<int>& data, int k){
    if(k >= data.size()) return 0; //если отрезков больше чем точек, то отрезки могут быть длиной 0 и лежать на каждой из точек
    
    std::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
    
    //границы поиска
    int left = 0;
    int right = data.back() - data.front();
    
    while(left < right){
            int mid = (left + right) / 2;
            
            if(CanCover(data, mid, k)) right = mid;
            else left = mid + 1;
    }
    
    return left;
}
```

Но как выяснилось в результате тестов, решение через бинарный поиск недостаточно быстрое. Может есть способ как найти минимальную длину отрезков без прохода по всем длинам? Что-нибудь наподобие жадного алгоритма, как для классической задачи?

Comment: *обратная задача - найти минимальную длину отрезков, когда по условию дан набор точек и количество отрезков .. решение через бинарный поиск недостаточно быстрое* Очевидно, что: 1) для нижней границы длины считать количество отрезков бессмысленно 2) верхнее приближение равно общей длине, делённой на количество отрезков 3) при бОльшей длине отрезков функция подсчёта минимального количества по крайней мере не медленнее, чем при меньшей длине 4) половинное деление быстрее инкремента. Соответственно скорректируйте `int right =` и `else left =`.

Comment: @Akina 3. Не вижу, чтобы эту функцию можно было улучшить. 4. В бинпоиске (else) возможностей для улучшения тоже не вижу.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно, я просто плохо понимаю код, С++ явно не моя стихия.

Comment: Если использовать дерево отрезков, то можно изменить скорость выполнения CanCover, предположительно, в лучшую сторону. Обращаю внимание на аккуратность формулировки: я не уверен во влиянии на асимптотику и я не уверен, что худший случай не эквивалентен двум линейным проходам.

Comment: В функции `CanCover` не нужно перебирать все точки. Если дан левый конец отрезка и его длина, его правый конец локализуется в массиве `data` за логарифм двоичным поиском. Сейчас `CanCover` имеет сложность *O(len(data))*, а будет *O(k * log(len(data)))*. Для небольших *k* будет заметное улучшения по скорости.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на проверяющую систему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Алгоритм эффективнее пока не придумывается, но есть несколько замечаний:

> ```
> for(int& elem : data){
> ```
>
> ```
> for(const int& elem : data){
> ```

Это медленнее, чем просто

```
for (int elem : data) {
```

> ```
> int right = data.back() - data.front();
> ```

Очевидно, что можно точнее:

```
int right = (data.back() - data.front() + k - 1) / k;
```

Ещё в качестве оптимизации можно проверить k==1.